# Python Json to dataframe is not importing all columns

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I'm trying to put a json file into a dataframe using this script

```
import pandas as pd

json = 'sof.json'

df = pd.read_json(json)

print(df)
```

but it's loading to the dataframe only 3 columns I think maybe because the information in the column 'config' is a nested json.

```
  utcTime                                             config  sourceID
0  1661397791  {'toothSettings': [{'length': 0.52312962962962...       253
1  1661958325  {'toothSettings': [{'length': 0.52312962962962...       275
2  1661952893  {'toothSettings': [{'length': 0.50300925925925...       276
3  1661956026  {'toothSettings': [{'length': 0.50300925925925...       254
```

**This is the JSON file**

```
[
    {
        "utcTime": 1661397791,
        "config": {
            "toothSettings": [
                {
                    "length": 0.5231296296296296,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5231296296296296,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 1,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.512824074074074,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.512824074074074,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 2,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5231296296296296,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5231296296296296,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 3,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5129222222222222,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5129222222222222,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 4,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5256814814814815,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5256814814814815,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 5,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 6,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5180259259259259,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5180259259259259,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 7,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 8,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 9,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        "sourceID": 253
    },
    {
        "utcTime": 1661958325,
        "config": {
            "toothSettings": [
                {
                    "length": 0.5231296296296296,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5231296296296296,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 1,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.512824074074074,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.512824074074074,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 2,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5030092592592592,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5030092592592592,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 3,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.4931944444444444,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.4931944444444444,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 4,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.4852444444444445,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.4852444444444445,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 5,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 6,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.4781777777777777,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.4781777777777777,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 7,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 8,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 9,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        "sourceID": 275
    },
    {
        "utcTime": 1661952893,
        "config": {
            "toothSettings": [
                {
                    "length": 0.5030092592592592,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5030092592592592,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 1,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.49231111111111103,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.49231111111111103,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 2,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.46276851851851847,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.46276851851851847,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 3,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.47346666666666665,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.47346666666666665,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 4,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.4852444444444445,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.4852444444444445,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 5,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 6,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.49810185185185174,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.49810185185185174,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 7,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 8,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "maxLength": 0.52,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 9,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        "sourceID": 276
    },
    {
        "utcTime": 1661956026,
        "config": {
            "toothSettings": [
                {
                    "length": 0.5030092592592592,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5030092592592592,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 1,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.49231111111111103,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.49231111111111103,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 2,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.48288888888888887,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.48288888888888887,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 3,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.47346666666666665,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.47346666666666665,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 4,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.4852444444444445,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.4852444444444445,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 5,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.48053333333333326,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 6,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.4781777777777777,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.4781777777777777,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 7,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5005555555555555,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 8,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                },
                {
                    "length": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "lengthAlgo": 0.5205777777777777,
                    "maxLength": 0.615,
                    "minLength": 0.4,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "toothNum": 9,
                    "lowConfidence": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        "sourceID": 254
    }
]
```

Do you know how can I have all the information contained in the column 'config' in separate columns?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.read_json("data.json")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("config").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df = df.explode("toothSettings")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("toothSettings").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df["utcTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["utcTime"], unit="s")
print(df.head(10).to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | utcTime | sourceID | length | lengthAlgo | maxLength | minLength | offset | status | toothNum | lowConfidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.52313 | 0.52313 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.512824 | 0.512824 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.52313 | 0.52313 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.512922 | 0.512922 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.525681 | 0.525681 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.520578 | 0.520578 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.518026 | 0.518026 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.520578 | 0.520578 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-08-25 03:23:11 | 253 | 0.520578 | 0.520578 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-31 15:05:25 | 275 | 0.52313 | 0.52313 | 0.52 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you Andrej, the script works flawlessly.